# How to handle examples that show bad practice but are otherwise correct?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Example for one such example: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1574/lock-statement/7002/singleton-object-using-lock#t=201607221307530232781

The example shows a singleton being initialized in it's getter by usage of `lock`. While it does work and does show correct usage of `lock`, [Singletons in on itself are bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/937093).

Please understand that this is only an example and this discussion shouldn't be focused on this example and wether or not the Singleton pattern is useful in some rare cases.

So - should valid examples that show bad practice be allowed to stay? Or should they be rewritten/removed as to prevent the spread of 'bad practice' patterns and ideas?

Comment: Do note that there is a highly upvoted comment on the linked answer which disagrees that singletons are a bad practice in and of themselves...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of correct examples that are in need of improvement through edits are two paths:

1. Edit and improve yourself.
2. Make an 'Improvement Request' so that someone else can make the example even better.

[image]

Comment: I understand that, the question is wether this is 'wanted' or not. The system could get 'flooded' to some degree with 'bad paractice reports' like this and people might get annoyed by that and claim that the example does work and thus does not warrant an improvement. I'd rather see this being discussed now, before things get heated.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Improvements are always wanted in a wiki-based system, but I realize that the definition of an improvement is subjective. Perhaps a better discussion question is "How do we define best practices when writing examples?"